# Force email receipt for Form submission in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a method in Google Script to force a receipt to be sent via email with a user's form submission? I see there is a way to do it within the Form itself, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this in the API.